# Including spaces in Angular characterLimit

Tags: angularjs

I am implementing a character countdown (similar to Twitter's) and am finding that the character count isn't counting spaces. How do I modify the following to include spaces as well as characters?

```
<span class="characterLimit" ng:bind="140 - result.shortName.length"></span>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default angular trims anything bound using `ng-model` in later versions (1.1.x as far as I know) you can turn off this behaviour using `ng-trim="false"`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="tweet" ng-trim="false">
```

I made a [demo of this here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yLMiaj?p=preview)